# How to plot an elliptic pde without using pdetool in matlab?

Tags: matlab, pde

Basically I want to plot this without using pdetool which is

> -div(c*grad(u))+a*u=f

Where a=0, c=1.0,f=10
Here I am having problem to use divergence(). It gives an error. For the time being I have written this code, though it works it doesn't give exactly what I expected.

```
a = 0.0; c = 1.0; f = 10; time = 100;

for step = 1:time    
    u = rand(50,50);    
    v = gradient(u);    
    f = -gradient(c*v)+a*u;

    %---------- show results    
    pcolor(f); 
    shading interp;    
    colorbar;
    colormap hsv;    
    drawnnow;    
end
```

Please help me to find a better solution with proper use of divergence. I want to study the chaotic behavior from it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "plotting an equation". One can plot a function, not an equation. Which function should be plotted?

Comment: I am sorry for that mistake. Yes indeed a function. I am looking for a particular ellipse formation in non linear systems following fisher equation after certain time. For that I need to perform the divergence function which I am unable to do in proper way.

Comment: Then it looks like you want to _solve_ the equation first? Plotting is the easy part, solving a PDE numerically is not as easy when you are coding from scratch.

Comment: Yeah actually. I can't solve it using the divergence function as it needs for inputs. But generally when solving manually we can easily perform del(dot)quantity but I can't perform it using divergence function. So that's why I can't plot it also.